# Cannot create EF foreign key mapping

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have two tables in SQL **User** and **UserDefaultModel** I have foreign key association

```
  <AssociationConnector Association="Ins_PricingDBModel.FK_UserDefaultModel_Users" 
    ManuallyRouted="false" />
```

I need to implement this same mapping using ModelBuilder. This is what I have tried

```
   modelBuilder.Entity<UserDefaultModel>() 
            .HasRequired(c=>c.User) 
            .WithMany() 
           .HasForeignKey(c => c.Id);

public class UserDefaultModel : Entity 
{ 

    public string DefaultModel { get; set; } 
    public virtual User User { get; set; } 
}
```

But still I am not able to map the values.Is the syntax valid ?

Comment: `.HasForeignKey(c => c.Id)` is probably not what you want. Either remove it in which case EF will maintain `User_Id` column for you, or add `public int UserId { get; set; }` in `UserDefaultModel` and use `.HasForeignKey(c => c.UserId)`.

Answer (score 0):

Models should look like:

```
public class User
{
    public User()
    {
    }

    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public int UserDefaultModelId { get; set; }

    public virtual UserDefaultModel UserDefaultModel { get; set; }
}

public class UserDefaultModel
{
    public UserDefaultModel()
    {
        Users = new List<User>();
    }

    public int UserDefaultModelId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

And one-to-many using FLuent API

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    //one-to-many 
    modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
                .HasRequired<UserDefaultModel>(s => s.UserDefaultModel) // User entity requires UserDefaultModel 
                .WithMany(u => u.Users); // UserDefaultModel entity includes many User entities

}
```

1. User entity requires UserDefaultModel
2. UserDefaultModel entity includes many User